# Can you tag this in HTML?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, tagging

I'm wondering if you can tag this with an ID in html. Lets say I am building an MVC app that returns some information in a datatable, and I want to be able to page through it. On the HTML part, I need to add a "pageNumber" that way I can stuff that value into a hidden field to return it to the controller so the app knows which page it's on. My question is, are you able to tag:

```
@{ int pageNumber = 0;}
```

with an ID so i can pass the value through an ajax call back to the controller? I've tried:

```
@{ int pageNumber = 0, new{id="currPage"};}
```

This did not work. Not exactly sure how you can tag this with an ID. Anyone?

Comment: What are you passing to the controller? Why not just have another parameter called `currPage`? with the value of the current page?

Comment: I don't want to make any changes to the model, it's all being done through an ajax call to the method. i want to use js to pull the current page number, then put it into a hidden field on the view, and when the ajax call is done, it will pass that pagenumber back to the controller.

Comment: You could just make your own class with the properties you want to pass back to the ajax call and then use JsonResult instead of actionresult